# how to use DiscretePlot to graph multiple partial sum functions?

Tags: plotting, summation, grid-layouts, filling

I am supposed to "**Make a table that shows {k,s1[k],s2[k],s3[k],s4[k],s5[k]}, for k from 1 to 50, and display as a Grid.**" but I have literally no idea how to do this (I'm not good with software). I tried to look it up, but got zero answers. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: @Syed well uh, thanks for the tip, but...that's way too much information. i don't have time to go through it all. I'd like a concise answer, if that's okay!

Comment: We do appreciate that you have joined the forum. The participants who are volunteering their time to support the Mathematica community will be disappointed to read `I don't have time to go through it all ...`. Homework questions are welcome, as long as the OP shows the meaningful steps taken so far and then seeks clarification on one unresolved issue. A minimal understanding of Mathematica is considered a starting point although the provision of undeserved help is also easy to find on community sites and such instances are (in my opinion) regrettable in general.

Comment: @Syed sorry that i offended you. i don't know things

Comment: `Grid@Table[{k, s1[k], s2[k], s3[k], s4[k], s5[k]}, {k, 1, 50}]` does what you asked. Presumably, you have definitions for the functions `s1` ... `s5`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you so much!